# Remove comma from last item in while loop

Tags: php

I have the following code which opens a CSV file and exports the results to a JSON format.

However, I'd like to remove the last `,` from the while loop. Can someone explain how I do this with my current code?

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$wantedColumns = array(3);
$row = 1;
 if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    echo '{
        "data": 
        [';

      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        if ($row == 1) {
            echo '<tr>';
        }else{
            echo '<tr>';
        }

        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if (!in_array($c,$wantedColumns)) continue;



            if(empty($data[$c])) {
               $value = "&nbsp;";
            }else{
               $value = $data[$c];
            }

            if ($row == 1) {
            }else{
                echo ''.$value.','; // comma added here
            }
        }

    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '</tr>';
    }else{
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    $row++;
    //$value= substr($value, 0, -1);
   }
            echo '  ]
                }';

  echo '</tbody></table>';
echo '</center>';   
    fclose($handle);
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: `$value= substr($value, -1, 1);` or `$value = rtrim($value, ',');`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, John - should this replace where I have marked `// comma added here`?

Comment: Are you trying to convert a CSV file to a JSON string?  Can I suggest *not* manually building your JSON?  I suggest you build an array then use `json_encode()`.

Comment: @JohnConde I have tried this but the 2nd option removes the comma string from all my items and the first one doesn't work at all :(

Comment: You probably have it in the wrong place then

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, converting CSV to JSON. Ultimately I'm then going to convert it back into a CSV. I will look at `json_encode()` - thank you.

Comment: @JohnConde Here is where I added it: http://pastebin.com/agij0ZR0. Is this correct?

Comment: You're trying to convert to JSON? So what is all the HTML table code for?

Comment: Why the `if` statements if the output is always the same: `if ($row == 1) { echo '<tr>'; }else{ echo '<tr>'; }`

Comment: We can probably ignore that code, it's not what the issue is relating to here. I will post updated code shortly.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk OK, but you really should use the JSON encoding from PHP and not try to rebuild it. For example, do you have a unit test to find out if a data value that contains a quote is handled correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing things like this, I prefer to push the values on to an array and then use implode to join them up

```
    $values = array();
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        if (!in_array($c,$wantedColumns)) continue;



        if(empty($data[$c])) {
           $value = "&nbsp;";
        }else{
           $value = $data[$c];
        }

        if ($row == 1) {
        }else{
            $values[] = $value;
        }
    }

    echo implode(',', $values);
```

Comment: @MajorCaiger Thanks for this. I have tried to include this in my solution, but without success. I just want the final `,` to be removed.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk: The point is, instead of echoing out the values in your loop, you build the structure you want as an array then echo it out later.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk: The solution I posted should work. Implode would add the commas inbetween each value, and not add 1 on the end.

Comment: Sorry, I think I have explained this badly. I maybe should provide the file I'm using which will help explain this more.

Comment: Basically, it's removing the "last comma" on each loop, rather than the final one at the end, once the loop is complete.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Could you post an example input and desired output?

Comment: @MajorCaiger Will do shortly :)